# Kick start RE (Test set skipped) error using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was practicing on google kick start Round A 2016 ( Country Leader ) but iam getting error that says Runtime error and can't figure what is wrong.
here is my code
First one :

```
T = int(input().strip())
tries = []
for i in range(1, T + 1):
    N = int(input().strip())
    persons = list()
    for t in range(1, N + 1):
        persons.append(input().strip())
    tries.append(persons)

winners = []
for t in tries:
    points = 0
    temp = ''
    for per in t:
        per_ltr = per.replace(' ','')
        if len(set(per_ltr)) > points:
            points = len(set(per_ltr))
            temp = per
    winners.append(temp)
num = 1
for one in winners:
    print(f'Case #{num}: {one}')
    num += 1
```

another one :

```
T = int(input())
winner = []
for i in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    persons = []
    for j in range(N):
        persons.append(input())
    points = len(set(persons[0]))
    temp = persons[0]
    for per in persons:
        if len(set(per)) > points:
            points = len(set(per))
            temp = per
    winner.append(temp)
num = 1
for one in winner:
    print(f'Case #{num}: {one}')
    num += 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code on your own computer? Although competitive coding sites usually do not provide the actual error, you can find it out by running it. Please add the error to the question once you've got it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes i have tried it locally but i got no error it runs as expected with exit code 0.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Have they defined a range on the number of tries? It might be going over memory.

Comment: Yes it has a range of tries, i will check it.  Thanks